# Can't get Jquery Hide and show to work right. Part 2

Tags: jquery

I just can't seem to get the jquery tabs to work they way I need it.

Here is what I am trying:
Series of bios that each have a "full Bio" link that reveals more text below. 
Here is JS fiddle, 
http://jsfiddle.net/bh7fwkev/

html

```
<div class="biowrapper">
<div class="row bio">
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x390">
    </div>
    <div class="medium-8 columns">
        <h3>
            Dr. Len Futerman, DDS
        </h3>
        <h4>
            Subheadline lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </h4>
        <p>
            Positive copy about the individual’s involvement about your treatment. Example: All of yourprocedures have one thing in common: they’ll be performed safely, painlessly and quickly by Dr. Len Futerman— Hampton Roads’ only dental anasthesiologist.
        </p>
    <div class="medium-12 columns"><a href="#" class="biobutton"> FULL BIOGRAPHY</a></div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="specialreveal" style="min-width:100%; background-color:#333">
<div class="row" >
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="biowrapper">
<div class="row bio">

    <div class="medium-8 columns">
        <h3>
            Dr. Len Futerman, DDS
        </h3>
        <h4>
            Subheadline lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </h4>
        <p>
            Positive copy about the individual’s involvement about your treatment. Example: All of yourprocedures have one thing in common: they’ll be performed safely, painlessly and quickly by Dr. Len Futerman— Hampton Roads’ only dental anasthesiologist.
        </p>
    <div class="medium-12 columns" ><a href="#" class="biobutton" style="text-align:left"> FULL BIOGRAPHY</a></div>

    </div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x390">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="specialreveal" style="min-width:100%; background-color:#333">
<div class="row" >
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <div class="medium-6 columns">
        <h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <h4>TITLE</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


$(".specialreveal").hide();
$(this).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //here use preventDefault to stop page scroll to the top
            $(".biowrapper" ).find( ".specialreveal".show();

});
```

I can get the tabs to open just fine, but I don't know how, when one open, the other one closes. 
I've tried not(this) as well as siblings (but I don't think my html is practical for siblings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bh7fwkev/5/

script will be like this

```
$(function () {
    $(".specialreveal").hide();
    $('[href="#"]').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
    $(document).on("click", "a.biobutton", function (e) {
        var $currentSection = $(this).closest(".biowrapper").find(".specialreveal").toggle().end();
        //If you want to hide all other `specialreveal` sections
        $(".biowrapper").not($currentSection).find(".specialreveal").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response! How do I get any other one that is open to close?

Comment: wow THanks! I tried not (this), looks like you put it "this" as a variable, and then used .not($currentSection) to hide? Or am I missing something? I'd really like to learn it properly.

Comment: @Deedub `this` refers to current instance. i.e., `this` gives the element on which element click happend